# Debian Buster XFCE: make PCManFM default, including for Open a Directory, as in Chromium - downloads - show in folder

Tags: debian, xfce, mime-types, file-manager, xdg

Using Debian Buster XFCE.  XFCE is married to Thunar, so cannot remove thunar.
I would prefer Chromium (or any other app that might choose to open a directory), as when viewing Downloads and clicking 'show in folder', that PCManFM be used to open the folder.

Have already:

- Set default File Manager in 'Preferred Applications'.
- Created a `pcmanfm.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`
- Edited `mimeapps.list` in `~/.local/share/applications/` (also `~/.config/`)
- Did `xdg-mime default pcmanfm.desktop inode/directory` and confirmed output of `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`.

Comment: Oh, defaults... I wish managing them were simpler. Maybe [this Arch Linux article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications) will be of help.

Comment: Thanks, I had stumbled across that page, but failed to read far enough to see the value. While not specific, it's a good overview.
Just tried command:  xdg-open ~/folder/ and it indeed opens PCManFM, so the question becomes, what is Chromium doing different that it instead uses Thunar?

Comment: Also tried using STRACE:  strace -o outputfile chromium.  Then do 'show in folder', and exit.  Expected to find in the output some reference to xdg-open, or at least part of the path of the folder Thunar opened, but did not find any more clues. This is my first use of strace, so perhaps I've not properly told it what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you have a look at [How to set which application is launched by xdg-open](https://askubuntu.com/q/18418)?

Comment: I have, but that link primarily deals with setting default web-browser.  My issue is I have set the default File-Manager to PCManFM, but with XFCE as my DE, neither Chromium nor FireFoxESR will respect that choice when I click 'show in folder' on an item in the browser's list of recent downloads.

Comment: Since, have also run commands:  xdg-open ./folder/ 
and exo-open --launch FileManager ./folder/
Both commands result in opening the folder using the preferred app 'PCManFM', so it would appear my preference has been properly set, yet browsers are somehow ignoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pcmanfm doesn't support DBus interface yet (it might change in future versions). You could block this interface for opening files.

Create a config file with the name `/etc/dbus-1/session-local.conf`
with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-freedesktopDTD D-Bus Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">

<busconfig>
  <policy context="default">
    <!-- Block all usage of org.freedesktop.FileManager1 for opening files -->
    <deny send_interface="org.freedesktop.FileManager1" send_destination="org.freedesktop.FileManager1"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Then reload dbus with the command:

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ReloadConfig
```

Comment: appears dbus support may now exist:
https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/pull/1525